# Does Heroku require a SSL certificate to execute cloud code that queries or uses the MongoAtlas DB? I can't post to my cloud functions

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I have a Parse Server on Heroku with a Atlas DB. I can't get cloud code that does database operations to work. I have read every question about my error, tried numerous configs.After build  I get a can't connect to https://someappname.heroku.com cloud code and push might not be available. Is this a build error, Heroku platform error, or something else? The cloud functions work when they just return a response or serve a page.

If I have a cloud function that queries something, I get a can not post to parse/classes/foo. error and I am out of ideas.

Comment: Are the queries directly to the classes working? Would you mind to share an example of cloud code that is not working and also how you are calling the function and the error message that you receive back?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.